# Use different titles - and styles - for lists and sub-lists of acronyms (glossaries package)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am trying to add one main list of abbraviations and two subsection that contain other sub-lists of abbreviations with different titles in the frontmatter of my document, using the "acronym" from the `glossaries` package, and having the titles appear in the table of content as "List of Abbreviations" (main title), "Time" (subsection), "Cities" (subsection).

Is there a way to split the acronyms in main and subsets with a a title each? 
I can see that this is possible for example using the `\newglossary` command if it is a glossary and then specifying the "type" when defining a new term for the glossary, but is there a similar function for acronyms? 
I am also trying to slightly change the style of the two lists acronyms by for example adding `\texttt`.

Thanks very much for any help, muuuuch appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
%Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations} 
\renewcommand*\acronymname{Time}
\newacronym{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}

\renewcommand*\acronymname{Cities}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}


\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\listoffigures  % print list of figures
\listoftables  % print list of tables

\printglossaries

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

% Use the acronyms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt}.
\gls{ny} is 3 hours ahead of \gls{la}.

\end{document}
```

I have something working OK, but I still cannot get it to print the main acronyms and then the others as sub-lists correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage[style=long, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
 \makenoidxglossaries
 % The main title "List of Abbreviations with some acronyms should be printed first, followed by the subsections "Time" and "Cities"
 %\setglossarysection{section}
 \newglossary[alg1,nonumberlist, type=\acronymtype, section=subsection]{time}{acn1}{acr1}{Time}
 \newglossary[alg2,nonumberlist,type=\acronymtype, section=subsection]{cities}{acn2}{acr2}{Cities}

 % This entry is part of the main glossary
 \newglossaryentry{orange}{name=orange, description={an orange coloured fruit},first={Orange}}

\newglossaryentry{utc}{type=time, name=\textsf{UTC}, description={Coordinated Universal Time},first={Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)}}

\newglossaryentry{la}{type=cities, name=\textrm{LA}, description={Los Angeles},first={Los Angeles (LA)}}

%: ----------------------- list of figures/tables/acronyms ------------------------


 \begin{document}
 \frontmatter

 % TABLE OF CONTENTS
 \listoffigures % print list of figures
 \listoftables  % print list of tables

 \glsaddall       
 \clearpage
 \phantomsection
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
 \printglossary[title=List of Abbreviations, toctitle=List of Abbreviations]
 \printnoidxglossary[type=time]
 \printnoidxglossary[type=cities]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

% Use the acronyms
\gls{orange} is a main acronym, while \gls{utc} is part of a sub-list of acronyms called Time and \gls{la} is part of another sub-list of acronyms called Cities.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\newacronym` internally uses `\newglossaryentry` and has an optional argument that can be used to add any extra keys that the entry requires. There are two possible approaches. The first is to use child entries:

```
\documentclass{book}

% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,
 nopostdot,% Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
 style=tree,% use hierarchical style
 toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations} 

\newglossaryentry{time}{name=Time,description={}}

\newacronym[parent=time]{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym[parent=time]{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}

\newglossaryentry{cities}{name=Cities,description={}}

\newacronym[parent=cities]{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym[parent=cities]{ny}{NY}{New York}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\printglossaries

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

% Use the acronyms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt}.
\gls{ny} is 3 hours ahead of \gls{la}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

In this case the glossary style must be one that supports hierarchical entries, so I've chosen the `tree` style for the MWE. See the [Predefined Glossary Styles table](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:styles) in the user manual for other options (the maximum level needs to be 1 or more, but should not be one of the homograph styles).

The second approach is to define different glossaries and use the `type` key. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,
 nopostdot,% Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
 style=tree,% change as appropriate
 toc]{glossaries}

\newglossary{time}{gls2}{glo2}{Time}
\newglossary{cities}{gls3}{glo3}{Cities}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,description={an example}}

\newacronym[type=time]{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym[type=time]{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}

\newacronym[type=cities]{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym[type=cities]{ny}{NY}{New York}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\printglossary

\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
\setglossarysection{section}

\printglossary[type=time]
\printglossary[type=cities]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt}.
\gls{ny} is 3 hours ahead of \gls{la}.

\gls{sample} entry.

\end{document}
```

This puts the `main` glossary in a chapter (assuming you want that) but the two abbreviation glossaries are placed in sections. The result looks like:

[image: image of abbreviation glossaries]

The style no longer needs to be one that supports child entries, so you can change it to whatever is suitable.