# Use subglossaries and mcoltree for acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In [Use different titles - and styles - for lists and sub-lists of acronyms (glossaries package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256380/use-different-titles-and-styles-for-lists-and-sub-lists-of-acronyms-glossar) is a solution for a glossary with sub glossaries and hierarchical entries. In case of (short) acronyms it needs one complete line per entry.

Desired is one glossary with multiple childs in a hierachial structure and multicolumn entries. Every sub glossary should start in a new section while the parents like >Time< or >Cities< even displayed again as headlines.

Can't figure out how to bring Alternative 1 code (MWE below) to this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,
  nopostdot,% Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
  style=tree,% use hierarchical style
  toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations} 

\newglossaryentry{time}{name=Time,description={}}

\newacronym[parent=time]{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym[parent=time]{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}

\newglossaryentry{cities}{name=Cities,description={}}

\newacronym[parent=cities]{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym[parent=cities]{ny}{NY}{New York}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter

  \printglossaries

  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Introduction}

  % Use the acronyms
  \gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt}.
  \gls{ny} is 3 hours ahead of \gls{la}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you'd be better off having multiple glossaries instead of using a hierarchical approach:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,
  nopostdot,% Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
  section
  ]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}

\newglossary*{time}{Time}
\newglossary*{cities}{Cities}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[type=time]{utc}{UTC}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newacronym[type=time]{adt}{ADT}{Atlantic Daylight Time}

\newacronym[type=cities]{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym[type=cities]{ny}{NY}{New York}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter

  \chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
  \printglossaries

  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Introduction}

  % Use the acronyms
  \gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt}.
  \gls{ny} is 3 hours ahead of \gls{la}.

\end{document}
```

[image: image of abbreviation lists]

If you only have a few sectional divisions (time and cities in this case), it's easy enough to make sure the `\newglossary` lines are in the appropriate order.

Comment: I assume that multiple glossaries using more recources that one glossary with childs. Cause I've some problems with PDFLaTeX memories too (running this at the edge, LuaLaTeX is not yet available in all packages) I've the hope that subglossaries are lighter in the memory footprint.

Comment: It requires extra files for multiple glossaries (you can use the `savewrites` package option to reduce the number of registers), but each `\newglossaryentry` has to store not only the `name`, `short`, `long`, `description` but all the other associated keys, so although there are a few internal commands used for storage associated with each glossary type, there are far more internal commands used for each glossary entry. If you don't use the `main` glossary you can use `nomain` to prevent its automatic creation which will save some resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicola, as always very helpful and highly appreciated!